# Can't use is operator to check type of return data

Tags: flutter, dart, types

I have a problem with checking the return data type from the server with the defined model.

I can't compare the returned data type of **UserTest**. I want to check that the returned data is of type **UserTest**, **I logged respond and it has a property of UserTest** but (**response is UserTest**) not run.

```
Future<dynamic> loginApp() async {
try {
  final Map<String, dynamic> dataForm = new Map<String, dynamic>();

  dataForm["name"] = "eve.holt@reqres.in";      // hard for test
  dataForm["job"] = "123456";                   // hard for test
           
  var bodyJson = json.encode(dataForm);
  print("bodyJson $bodyJson");     // {"name":"eve.holt@reqres.in","job":"123456"}

  var response = await _apiNetworkPOST(endPoint: 'users', body: bodyJson);

  if (response is Map<String, dynamic>) {
    print("I am UserTest $response");  //=>> Data is available here

    if (response is UserTest) {   //=>> it not come here
      return UserTest.fromJson(response);
    }
  }

  return ErrorJson(message: response.toString());
} on Exception catch (e) {
  return FetchDataException(e.toString());
}
}
```

`print('I am UserTest $response');` result

`{name: eve.holt@reqres.in, job: 123456, id: 392, createdAt: 2021-09-29T09:43:31.290Z}`

My **UserTest** class:

```
class UserTest {

UserTest({
    this.name,
    this.job,
    this.id,
    this.createdAt,
  });

  final String? name;
  final String? job;
  final String? id;
  final DateTime? createdAt;

  factory UserTest.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      UserTest.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory UserTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserTest(
        name: json["name"],
        job: json["job"],
        id: json["id"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "job": job,
        "id": id,
        "createdAt": createdAt?.toIso8601String(),
      };
}
```

Thank you for all answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construct would only work if UserTest would inherit from the Map. There is no operator in dart to check if a map fits an object. You have to check manually if the Map contains the expected keys.

Comment: How do you usually use to check if the data sent from the server is correct or not?

Comment: Assume the return type is not UserTest but another format.

Comment: You have to check if the keys that you use in fromJson are all contained in the Map. The function is containsKey. Depending on how restrictive you want to be you can check that only these keys are contained over the lenght propertyof the Map